# How to accelerate autocomplete function with Django?

Tags: django, autocomplete, trie, django-autocomplete-light

I have implemented django-autocomplete-light on my website (Python 3.6.5 / Django 1.11.20) but retrieving results is very slow (www.capelight.com).

The source database is made of 12,000 names (cities, provinces, etc).
How can I accelerate this process ?

I have read that implementing a Trie strongly accelerates the process, but I have no clue how to do that. Or maybe django-autocomplete is already based on Trie ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto='name1, name2, name3...')